# incapable of Annihilation

Tags: phrase-meaning

> He has refused for a long time, after such dissolutions, to cause others to be elected; whereby the Legislative powers, **incapable of Annihilation**, have returned to the People at large for their exercise; the State remaining in the mean time exposed to all the dangers of invasion from without, and convulsions within.

Source: [The Declaration of Independence](https://www.archives.gov/founding-docs/declaration-transcript)

What does the phrase "incapable of Annihilation" mean? Annihilation means "complete destruction". What does the word mean in the context as described in the OP?  Annihilation of what?

Comment: The legislative powers cannot be annihilated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the phrase is describing the legislative powers. It is saying that those powers are indestructible, or the like.

Comment: What is it like if written in today's English for "incapable of Annihilation"?

Comment: That wording is fine for today's english. You could say "... who are invulnerable" or the like I suppose.

Comment: I think that my failure to get "whereby" there had contributed the problem of my understanding in the OP. Cambridge Dictionary defines it as "by which way or method" - is it the way of the King of Great Britain?

Answer (score 2):

Since 'incapable of Annihilation' means indestructible, or forever continuing on, perhaps the phrase could also be thus:
...that the Legislative powers, 'still and always in effect', have returned to the people at large for their exercise;...